# Star Wars Battlefront 2: On-Screen Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse, star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

If this is the wrong section for this, please let me know...

I was given Battlefront 2 as a gift. I'm handicapped and use the Windows 10 on screen keyboard for everything. But the game locks/hides the mouse. So I can't use the on screen keyboard to play. Am I able to release the mouse somehow? Or any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried playing  borderless rather than fullscreen. Have you done so? Was there any effect?

Comment: I tried borderless and windowed.  Same issue.

Comment: Are you able to play other games with the onscreen keyboard? If so, please name a couple

Comment: Try refunding the game and tell Electronic Arts you are not supporting their greed and gambling practices. Worked for me 100% I wouldn't be surprised if compatibility to your keyboard comes in a lootbox with a 1% chance to have it.

Comment: Final Fantasy, LOTRO, Sims all work...but they don't hide the mouse.